# How can I port forward without access to my router?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apache2, portforwarding

I have a small django project running on my Ubuntu laptop; I am developing it with a friend. Since we live in different states I want him to be able to interact with my website outside my network since he's going to be helping me evaluate it on a daily or weekly basis.

I currently have a working apache2 server running my django website. I can't port forward because the internet in my campus apartment is managed by the building admin. It's nothing fancy, really, it's just a standard Spectrum router.

Is there a way I can port forward using only my Ubuntu Laptop?

I read this on quora:

https://www.quora.com/How-can-I-port-forward-in-Debian-based-Linux-without-router-or-using-cellular-data-or-portable-mobile-WiFi

and by the looks of it; this seems to be at the OS level? is that enough?

also, would I be able to do this method on any standard network I connect? like my grandma's?

Any guidance is appreciated

Comment: Firstly your question is not a programming issue, and as such not appropriate for [so] (should rather be on [su] or [unix.se]) ... secondly the method described in the quora article won't solve your problem, that only describes how to forward a port locally on your PC, e.g. you have a webserver running on 7777 that you can't change, but want to be able to reach it with a browser w/o having to type :7777 at the end of the host section of the URL.

Comment: To program collaboratively with each other, you can use JetBrains PyCharm (https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) with CodeWithMe (https://www.jetbrains.com/code-with-me/) or AWS Cloud9 (https://aws.amazon.com/cloud9/).
To make your local server available locally over the network, you can tunnel it to the Internet using tools like ngrok (https://ngrok.com) or localtonet (https://localtonet.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I sorry if I am not understanding correctly, you have internet access but not admin control of the router? you could still port traffic to your apache server but network firewalls would probably stop you on that one.

I would highly recommend google colab I think it would be your best choice as you could sync your hard drives source to google colab for your buddy to check in on your coding...